# WPF telerik RadRibbonView and RadRibbonWindow

Tags: wpf, telerik-radribbonbar

I am using Telerik WPF UI `RadRibbonWindow`, `RadRibbonView` in my application. I have inherited `RadRibbonWindow` in the `MainWindow` class. I have added the proper Dlls for that with same version, but the control is not visible in Window. How can I solve this visibility problem? The project is building successfully.

Comment: Please add some code, show how you inherited RadRibbonWindow, show your XAML and application errors output if any.

Answer (score 0):

```
<telerik:RadRibbonWindow x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<telerik:RadRibbonView x:Name="theRibbon"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <!-- Ribbon Tab #1: Home -->
    <telerik:RadRibbonTab Header="Home" telerik:KeyTipService.AccessText="H">
        <telerik:RadRibbonGroup Header="Clipboard">
            <telerik:RadRibbonButton LargeImage="/Resources/Icons/cut.png" Text="Cut"/>
            <telerik:RadRibbonButton LargeImage="/Resources/Icons/paste.png" Text="Paste" />
            <telerik:RadRibbonButton LargeImage="/Resources/Icons/copy.png" Text="Copy" />
        </telerik:RadRibbonGroup>
        <telerik:RadRibbonGroup Header="Show">
            <telerik:RadRibbonButton Text="Close Table"  Size="Large"
                           LargeImage="/Resources/Icons/closetable.png"/>
            <telerik:RadRibbonButton Text="Close All"  Size="Large"
                            LargeImage="/Resources/Icons/closeall.png"/>

            <!--<Fluent:Button Header="Close Table" Click="CloseTable_Click" SizeDefinition="Large, Middle, Small"
                           Icon="/Resources/Icons/closetable.png" LargeIcon="/Resources/Icons/closetable.png"/>-->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="True" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="15" Height="15" 
                         />
                <telerik:Label Content="Status bar" Padding="0" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="True"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="15" Height="15">
                </CheckBox>
                <telerik:Label Content="Folder list" Padding="0" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </telerik:RadRibbonGroup>
        <telerik:RadRibbonGroup Header="Publish">
            <telerik:RadRibbonButton Name="printBtn" LargeImage="/Resources/Icons/print.png" Text="Print..." telerik:KeyTipService.AccessText="P" />
            <telerik:RadRibbonButton Name="exportBtn" LargeImage="/Resources/Icons/export.png" Text="Export..." telerik:KeyTipService.AccessText="E" />
        </telerik:RadRibbonGroup>
        <telerik:RadRibbonGroup Header="Edit">
            <telerik:RadToggleButton Name="lockBtn" />
            <telerik:RadRibbonButton Name="appendRowBtn" Size="Large, Medium, small" SmallImage="/Resources/Icons/appendrow.png" 
                           LargeImage="/Resources/Icons/appendrow.png" Text="Append Row" />
            <telerik:RadRibbonButton Name="addAboveBtn"  LargeImage="/Resources/Icons/addabove.png" 
                          Text="Add Above"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <telerik:RadRibbonButton Name="addBelowBtn" LargeImage="/Resources/Icons/addbelow.png" Text="Add Below" />
            <telerik:RadRibbonButton Name="deleteRowBtn" LargeImage="/Resources/Icons/deleterow.png"  Text="Delete Row" />
            <telerik:RadRibbonButton Name="commitBtn"  Size="Medium" SmallImage="/Resources/Icons/commit.png" Text="Commit"  />
            <telerik:RadRibbonButton Name="rollbackBtn" Size="Medium" SmallImage="/Resources/Icons/commit.png" Text="Rollback"/>
        </telerik:RadRibbonGroup>
        <telerik:RadRibbonGroup Header="Font">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2,5">
                <telerik:RadComboBox Name="fontComboBox" Width="120" Margin="0" IsEditable="True"
                          ToolTip="Font" SelectedIndex="0"
                          IsReadOnly="True" >
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Content="Time New Roman"/>
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Content="Arial"/>
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Content="Century Gothic"/>
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Content="Comic Sans MS"/>
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Content="Calibri"/>
                </telerik:RadComboBox>
                <telerik:RadComboBox Name="fontSizeComboBox" Width="40"
                      ToolTip="Font Size"
                      SelectedIndex="1"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      IsEditable="True"
                      Margin="0" >
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Content="10"/>
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Content="12"/>
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Content="14"/>
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Content="16"/>
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Content="18"/>
                </telerik:RadComboBox>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                    <CheckBox Name="AltCheckBox" Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Alternate"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </telerik:RadRibbonGroup>
        <telerik:RadRibbonGroup Header="Search">
            <TextBox x:Name="searchBox" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" Margin="2" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"   />
        </telerik:RadRibbonGroup>
    </telerik:RadRibbonTab>
</telerik:RadRibbonView>
```

and I am inheriting as: 
public partial class MainWindow :RadRibbonWindow { public MainWindow () { InitializeComponent (); }

dlls added by me:
Telerik.Windows.Controls, Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input, Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation, Telerik.Windows.Controls.RibbonView, I have added these assemblies with same versions. 2016.2.613.45 And I am Using VS2013 Telerik.Windows.Controls.Data,

what changes should i made in code so that RadRibbonWindow will be visible in mainWindow, here I have created WPF Application project.